# Is the half-wave potential concentration dependent?

Tags: electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

As I was refreshing my knowledge on cyclic voltammetry, I came across the following doubt.

Is the half-wave potential concentration dependent or is it not?

[image]

If we look at this graph, let's assume we have a reversible redox couple. The half wave potential $E_{1/2}$ is defined to be $\frac{E_{pc}+E_{pa}}{2}$, and is equal to the standard formal potential $E^{0}$. For example, if we did the ferrocene/ferrocenium CV experiment in 10 mM, 20 mM or 30 mM concentrations, would the resulting half wave potential $E_{1/2}$ always be the same or would it deviate, why or why not?

Edit: What is the physical explanation why the half wave potential is always around the formal potential of the redox couple, regardless of the concentrations?

Comment: So as you said, the halfway potential is equal to the formal potential for a reversible redox couple. However, is the formal potential dependent on concentration? The answer is yes, the activity of either species is dependent on the electrolyte specifications. Which is already one reason why the halfwave potential will shift with changing concentrations of reactants.

Comment: Okay you are right. But what is the physical explanation why the half wave potential is always around the formal potential of the redox couple, regardless of the concentrations?

Comment: What would be the physical explanation for the half wave potential not being around the formal potential of the redox couple?

Comment: @Poutnik yeah I don’t know why the half wave potential is around the formal potential, it was always a given in my electrochemistry course.